# zendframework 2 Doctrine 2 my post form is not returning the values

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

i am a little baffled by this;

my post forms is not populating the values received from the **returned post values**; i suspect the problem is arising from my **getJobId()** in my jobsort class values;

below is my form:

```
public function jobSortAction()
    {

         $form = new CreateJobSortForm($this->getEntityManager());

         $jobSort = new JobSort();

         $form->setInputFilter($jobSort->getInputFilter());

         $id= 11;
         $jobSort->setId($id);

         $form->bind($jobSort);

         if ($this->request->isPost()) {
  //$post     = $this->request->getPost();      
             $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
  //var_dump($post);
  //var_dump($jobSort);               

             if ($form->isValid()) {


                  $this->getEntityManager()->persist($jobSort);
                 $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
             }
         }
         return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

below is the var_dumped values of the 'return post values' and the Jobsort() object. You will note that the returned post values has values for both the Id and the JobId

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[168]
  public 'JobSort' => 
    array (size=2)
      'jobId' => string '5' (length=1)
      'id' => string '11' (length=2)
  public 'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)

object(Workers\Entity\JobSort)[394]
  protected 'inputFilter' => null
  protected 'id' => int 11
  protected 'jobId' => null
  protected 'workerservicelist' => null
```

yet, when i populate the values, it does not seem to record the values for the jobId

**below is my jobsort entity class:**

```
class JobSort  
{
   protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="jobId", type="integer")
     */
    protected $jobId;


 public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->id = $id;
    }


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setJobId($jobId)
    {
        return $this->jobId = $jobId;
    }

    public function getJobId( )
    {
        return $this->jobId;
    }
```

is there any advice or suggestions on what i need to do to find out why the values are not been populated

warm regards

Andreea

**by the way;** the form actually works when i had the Id of CLASS jobsort set to 
 @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

the problem started when i took it out and set it to manual

Hello again

here is my form:

this is the error message i received;

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO worker_main_jobsort (user_id, jobId) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [11, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'jobId' cannot be null
```

**here is my form:**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Workers\Form\Fieldset\JobSortFieldset;

class CreateJobSortForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('create-Job-post-form');

        // The form will hydrate an object of type "BlogPost"
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\JobSort'));

        // Add the user fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
        $JobSortFieldset = new JobSortFieldset($objectManager);
        $JobSortFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($JobSortFieldset);


        // Optionally set your validation group here


        // … add CSRF and submit elements …

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        )); 

        // Optionally set your validation group here
    }
}
```

**and here is the fieldset class:**

```
class JobSortFieldset extends Fieldset 
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('JobSort');
        $id= 10;
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\JobSort'))
             ->setObject(new JobSort());


        }
}
```

**this addition is in response to  rafaame solution;**

i amended my form as recommended; however it still not working. i think the issue now is that Rafaame solution is in regarding to zendDB **save method**, but i am using doctrine **persis**t and **flush** method . i accordingly get the following error message;

Call to undefined method Workers\Entity\JobSort::save()

below is my amended form:

```
public function jobSortAction()
    {
         $form = new CreateJobSortForm($this->getEntityManager() );

         $jobSort = new JobSort();

         if($this->request->isPost())
        {
             $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

             if ($form->isValid())
             {
                $entity = $form->getData();
                $model = new JobSort();
                $model->save($entity);

               // $this->getEntityManager()->persist( $model);
             //   $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
             }
         }
         return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

in response to Rafaame question about what problems i had,the message that i am now receiving is this: 
**

> EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object,
>   array given.

**

**below is my function:**

```
public function jobSortAction()
    {
         $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
         $objectManager = $this->getEntityManager();

         $form = new CreateJobSortForm($this->getEntityManager());

         if ($this->request->isPost())
         {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

             if ($form->isValid()) {
                 $entity = $form->getData();

              $model = new JobSort($objectManager, $serviceLocator);
              $model->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
              $model->getEntityManager()->flush();

             }
         }
        return array('form' => $form);
     }
```

my form; i.e where the hydrator should be set

```
namespace Workers\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Workers\Form\Fieldset\JobSortFieldset;

class CreateJobSortForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('JobSort');

        // The form will hydrate an object of type "BlogPost"
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\JobSort'));

        // Add the user fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
        $JobSortFieldset = new JobSortFieldset($objectManager);
        $JobSortFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($JobSortFieldset);
```

Comment: Could you paste your form code? Thanks

Comment: hello Rafaame. i have edited my page to include the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your code, you are creating a JobSort entity, setting only its *id* and binding it to the form:

```
$jobSort = new JobSort();
$jobSort->setId($id);
$form->bind($jobSort);
```

After that, you are dumping $jobSort and $this->request->getPost(). So, obviously, you are getting jobId in the POST data but not in the entity (you didn't set the entity's jobId before binding it to the form). There's nothing wrong with your entity's code.

The solution for this: don't bind anything to the form. You should only bind an entity to the form in the case of an *edit* action, that you fetch the entity from the database and want to populate the form with its values.

Example of *add* action:

```
public function addAction()
{

    $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();

    $form = new Form\EmailCampaign\Add($serviceLocator, $objectManager);

    if($this->request instanceof HttpRequest && $this->request->isPost())
    {

        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

        if($form->isValid())
        {

            $entity = $form->getData();

            //If you want to modify a property of the entity (but remember that it's not recommended to do it here, do it in the model instead).
            //$entity->setJobId(11);

            $model = new Model\EmailCampaign($serviceLocator, $objectManager);
            $model->save($entity);

            if($entity->getId())
            {

                $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Email campaign successfully added to the database.');
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/wildcard', ['controller' => 'email-campaign', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $entity->getId()]);

            }
            else
            {

                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('There was an error adding the email campaign to the database. Contact the administrator.');

            }

        }

    }

    return new ViewModel
    ([

        'form' => $form,

    ]);

}
```

Example of *edit* action:

```
public function editAction()
{

    $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();

    $form = new Form\EmailCampaign\Edit($serviceLocator, $objectManager);

    $id = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
    $entity = $objectManager
                ->getRepository('Application\Entity\EmailCampaign')
                ->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    if($entity)
    {

        $form->bind($entity);

        if($this->request instanceof HttpRequest && $this->request->isPost())
        {

            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

            if($form->isValid())
            {

                //If you want to modify a property of the entity (but remember that it's not recommended to do it here, do it in the model instead).
                //$entity->setJobId(11);

                $model = new Model\EmailCampaign($serviceLocator, $objectManager);
                $model->save($entity);

                $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Email campaign successfully saved to the database.');

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {

        $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('A email campaign with this ID was not found in the database.');
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', ['controller' => 'email-campaign']);

    }

    return new ViewModel
    ([

        'form' => $form,
        'entity' => $entity,

    ]);

}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

What I provided was an example of how to handle the form and the entities with Doctrine 2 + ZF2.

What you have to keep in mind is that Doctrine doesn't work with the concept of models, it just understands entities. The model I'm using in my application is a concept of the MVC (Model-View-Controller) design pattern (that ZF2 uses) and I have decided to wrap the entity manager calls (persist and flush) inside my model's method, that I named *save()* (in the case the entity needs some special treatment before being save to the database and also because it is not a good practice to use the entity manager directly in the controller - see this slide of Marcos Pivetta presentation http://ocramius.github.io/presentations/doctrine2-zf2-introduction/#/66).

Another thing that you may be misunderstanding is that when you do *$form->getData()* to a form that has the DoctrineObject hydrator, it will return you the entity object, and not an array with the data (this last happens if it has no hydrator). So you don't need to create the entity after doing *$form->getData()*, and if you do so, this created entity won't have any information provided by the form.

Your code should work now:

```
public function jobSortAction()
{
     $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
     $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

     $form = new CreateJobSortForm($entityManager);

     if ($this->request->isPost())
     {

        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

         if ($form->isValid()) {

             //I'm considering you are setting the DoctrineObject hydrator to your form,
             //so here we will get the entity object already filled with the form data that came through POST.
             $entity = $form->getData();

             //Again, if you need special treatment to any data of your entity,
             //you should do it here (well, I do it inside my model's save() method).
             //$entity->setJobId(11);

             $entityManager->persist($entity);
             $entityManager->flush();

         }

     }

    return array('form' => $form);

 }
```

Comment: hi rafaame. thank you for your help so far. unfortunetly, i am still having problems. i think your solution is not for doctrine2. i.e doctrine uses the persist adn flush method. do you know how i can amend your solution. i enclosed the code above

Comment: Hello andreea115, my solution is for Doctrine 2. The persist and flush calls are implicit inside the save() method of the model. You may replace the $model->save($entity) line for $objectManager->persist($entity); $objectManager->flush(). What problems are you having now?

Comment: hello again Rafaame, sorry for the contiued trouble in this matter. i have enclosed above the error report that i am now receiving. would really appriciate some advice on how to proceed. warm regards Andreea

Comment: Hello andreea115, please check my answer's edit. I hope this helps. Well, if you hit the +1 button (up arrow on the left of my answer) I would by grateful.

Comment: Hello Rafaame. i am so sorry but i am still having problems. the doctrine hydrator does not seem to set on my form; i therefore only receive an array from the return post. i have attached the code above; you will see that i actually set the hydrator. any idea why its not been set

Comment: i var_dumped the  $form->setData($this->request->getPost()) and this does indeed return an object. however, when i then did the $form->getData(); it was minus an object and just returned an array

Comment: You should use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as a hydrator and do $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($entityManager)).

Comment: Ops, just saw you are already doing this. Really dunno then, sorry :/

Comment: Hello Rafaame. thank you so much for your brilliant help; i am  extremely grateful for your kind and detailed explanation of the problem. i have finally got it to work. the final problem was that the entityManager was not being passed to the JobSort Entity field.